# Could subcomponents of a component with a stereotype have different stereotypes?

Tags: components, uml

I'm struggling to understand if I use stereotype **User Interface** for a component, does it imply that all of its subcomponents are **User Interface** as well? 
For instance, I have a component named [User Profile] which has been stereotyped as **User Interface**, but I have a couple of internal subcomponents inside [User Profile] just for internal use by [User Profile]component itself or other components of the system. For instance, a subcomponent call [User Manager] that is connected to db to fetch all the user's reservation, etc. [User Manager] component has several interfaces but not necessarily GUI for end users. In such cases is that correct if I put [User Manager] inside [User Profile] as its subcomponent?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare stereotype with metatype. A stereotype refines the standard UML metatypes.

There is no rule that a component can only own other components (of the exact same metatype), so UML allows you to add components (or other elements) with other stereotypes as owned elements (which is what you are referring to when you mean sub-component I guess).

Whether it makes sense in the context of this specific stereotype can only be answered by the author of the profile that defines this stereotype.